# Flutter PopScope is not working whlie using popUntil

Tags: android, flutter, dart, back

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false, // false or true
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
        Navigator.popUntil(
            context, ModalRoute.withName(RouterHelper.logInScreen));
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 312,
                child: 'Main Screeen'.toText(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  maxLine: 2,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontFamily: poppinsMedium,
                  color:Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

whlie we are using **canPop false or true** both have same senario that **popUntil** is not working in **onPopInvoked**.

I have tried to change **canPop: true**, but still get same result it will cause crash the app. and route is not being routed backword. And also I use **canPop: false** and write

```
canPop: false,
onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

in **PopScope** same causing the crash of the app. I can't be able to use **Navigator.pop** and **Navigator.popUntil** in **PopScope**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this new version. may be it's useful for you.

```
PopScope(
          canPop: false,
          onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
            if (didPop) {
              return;
            }
             Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(RouterHelper.logInScreen));
          },
  ),
```

Comment: onWillPop feature was deprecated after Flutter version v3.12.0-1.0.pre. I'm talking about the latest onPopInvoked which is now the latest function of PopScope